# Testing simple Null vs simple Alternative.

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f$. Suppose we want to test $$H_0:f=f_0\quad $$ against $$ H_1:f=f_1$$. For any $\alpha>0$, define

$$T_\alpha(X)= 1\qquad if\quad f_1(X)>c(\alpha)f_0(X)$$
$$\qquad=\gamma(\alpha)\qquad if\quad f_1(X)=c(\alpha)f_0(X)$$
$$\qquad=0\qquad if\quad f_1(X)<c(\alpha)f_0(X)$$

where $0\le\alpha\le1$, $c(\alpha)\geq 0$ and $E[T_\alpha(X)]=\alpha$ under $H_0$. Can we show

(i) if $\alpha_1\lt\alpha_2$ then $c(\alpha_1)\geq(\alpha_2)$

(ii) if $\alpha_1\lt\alpha_2$ then type II error probability of $T_{\alpha_1}(X)$ is larger than that of $T_{\alpha_2}(X)$.

When using $\alpha_1\le\alpha_2 \implies E[T_{\alpha_1}(X)]\le E[T_{\alpha_2}(X)]$ I am arriving at conclusions that are not at all informative. Please help.

Comment: Hi Neel, I did some editing , please check and let me know if I did a good job.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary.

Comment: No problem. I also meant in terms of whether I changed the meaning/intent of the question.

Comment: No no... The meaning of the question is fine after your editing.